# How to concatenate/change the error message if the input is not a valid date in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I tried this for almost two days but still nothing. Maybe someone can help who is highly skilled in javascript loops.

I asked this question before and change some code but still no luck in showing the expected data. And still struggling for this.

I have this code:

```
$(function(){
var len = $('#groupContainer > div').length;
var data = [];
for(var i=0; i < len; i++){

    var number = $('#number_' + [i + 1]);
    var date = $('#date_' + [i + 1]);
    var count = i + 1;
    var message ="";
    var a = number.map(function(){
        return this.value;
    });
    var b = date.map(function(){
        return this.value;
    });

    var newObj = {number: a[0], date: b[0]}
    data.push(newObj);
}

var message = "";
for(var c = 0; c < data.length; c++)
{        
    haveErrorInGroup = false;
    for(var d in data[c])
    {
        if(data[c].hasOwnProperty(d))
        {      
            if(data[c][d] == "")
            {
                if(!haveErrorInGroup){
                    haveErrorInGroup= true;
                   message += 'Group: ' + [c + 1] + '\n';
                }

                message +=  d + ' is required!\n';
            }
            if(d == "date")
            {
                if(data[c][d].length != 22 && data[c][d] != "")
                {
                    message += 'Invalid Date!\n';
                }

            }

        }

    }


}
if(message){
    alert(message);
}

});
```

And the expected output:

If all the fields in group 1 is filled and group 2 is not show alertbox:

```
   Group 2:
   Number is required!
   Date is required!
```

If all field is not filled show:

```
   Group 1, 2 Number is required!
   Group 1, 2 Date is required!
```

And if date is not really a date:

```
  Group 1, 2 Date is invalid.
```

And if one of the inputs is invalid.

```
  Group 2 Date is invalid.
```

If all field is filled do nothing.

Here's my **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aldrin27/z4yfohao/20/)**

Comment: Really - variables named `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`?  Makes your code much harder to read and understand when variables don't have meaningful names.

Comment: Sorry for that. It's just for testing purposes only.

Comment: it would make it easier to interpret your code with more meaningful variable names.

Comment: Yes. I'll change that if I will get through this.

Comment: Also remove the disgusting flattery and try to narrow down your problem.

Comment: The expected result is in the question. The problem is that I can't include the change text required to invalid in the date field. If the date field has been filled out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like [jquery-validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org). I'm pretty sure it comes with a native date validator but if you want to have a more specific format you can just put a regex into it.

Comment: No. I don't want a plugin. Thanks for attempting.

Comment: Ok, your decision, but that's how everybody out there is doing it. It saves a lot of time. Two days for input validation is not sustainable if you get paid ;)